# Wrap a JavaScript function reference

Tags: javascript, reactjs, kendo-treeview

I have the following JavaScript code, which works as expected...

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */

var TreeView = React.createClass({
  render: function() {    
  return <div ref="treeview"></div>;  
  },
 componentDidMount: function() {
   console.log(this.props.onChange);
   var tree = $(this.refs.treeview.getDOMNode()).kendoTreeView({
     dataSource: ...,
     dataTextField: "Name",
     select: this.props.onChange
     }
   });
 }
});

var MyApp = React.createClass({   
  onChange: function(e) {    
    console.log(e);
    this.setState({key: e});
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <TreeView onChange={this.onChange}/>  
        <GridView />         
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

However, with the kendo treeview, on selecting a tree node, the whole node is passed. To get at the underlying key, I would need to process the node as follows:

```
select: function(e) { 
  var id = this.dataItem(e.node).id;
  this.props.onChange(id);
}
```

However I've obviously not quite got it right since, and here please excuse my noobness, it seems that in the working instance a reference to the function is being used, whereas in the non-working instance, the function is actually being executed... Or something like that: the error message being returned is:

> Cannot call method 'onChange' of undefined.

So what would I need to do to be able to reference the function which extracts the key before calling the `onChange` method? Note that, if my understanding is correct, `onChange` needs to be executed in the context of the MyApp class so that any child components will get notified on the change.

EDIT: I've tried using partial application but am still not quite there. I've updated the `onChange` routine to take a function which returns the key from the node

```
onChange: function(getKey, e) {      
  this.setState({Key: getKey(e)});
},
```

But am not sure how to wire it all up.

Comment: the html in the return statement shouldn't work in JS. so there is probably an error that is causing MyApp to be undefined. You should see something like ... `SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

Comment: @Shanimal. Thx. Reactjs has a tool, JSX, which permits html-like statements in js. I've just edited the js to reflect the reference to the JSX lib for clarity

Comment: Cool. So I have to check that out. Im still confused though, it looks like you are doing everything correctly, but are you including the JSX Transformer in your html?

Comment: I added the line at the top. I don't really know much about JSX but that seems to be enough to make it work. Well that and the script ref in the index.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code looks mostly right. I believe your only problem is that the `select` callback you're passing to the treeview is being called with the wrong scope. Note that you're using `this` to mean two different things within the function (once for the actual tree view object and the other for the React component). Easiest solution is probably to store a reference to the onChange function like so:

```
componentDidMount: function() {
   var onChange = this.props.onChange;
   var tree = $(this.refs.treeview.getDOMNode()).kendoTreeView({
     dataSource: ...,
     dataTextField: "Name",
     select: function(e) { 
       var id = this.dataItem(e.node).id;
       onChange(id);
     }
   });
 }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Works. That is brilliant. TVM.